# Coriolis force effect on freely falling body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, projectile, coriolis-effect

If an object is let to fall freely from a tower of 100 meters, then it will get deflected towards East. Now clarify that if an object is allowed to fall freely from a rocket at 100 meters height. Does the deflection take place towards East also in this case?

Comment: This question may benefit from more details. If I recall correctly, the deflection depends on the direction of the rocket motion and on the latitude.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, this is an excellent thought exercise.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

lets look at the equations

the position vector of the body  is
$$\vec R=\left[ \begin {array}{c} x\\ y\\ 
z\end {array} \right] \quad\Rightarrow
\vec v=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \dot x\\ \dot y\\ 
\dot z\end {array} \right]
$$
the Coriolis force is

$$\vec F_c =-2\,m~(\vec\omega\times\vec{v})$$
where
$$\vec \omega= \left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\ \Omega\,\cos \left( 
\lambda \right) \\ \Omega\,\sin \left( \lambda
 \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

the Eom's

$$m\vec{\ddot{R}}=-m\,g\,\vec e_z+\vec F_c$$
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
  \ddot x \\
  \ddot{y} \\
  \ddot{z} \\
\end{bmatrix}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -2\, \left( \cos \left( \lambda \right) {
\dot z}-\sin \left( \lambda \right) {\dot y} \right) \Omega
\\ -2\,\Omega\,\sin \left( \lambda \right) {\dot  x}
\\ -g+2\,\Omega\,\cos \left( \lambda \right) {\dot x
}\end {array} \right] \tag 1
$$

the solutions of equation (1) with the initial condition $~z(0)=z_0~$ and all other initial conditions are zero  is

$$x(t)=\underbrace{\left(\frac 12\frac t\Omega-\frac 14\frac{\sin(2\,\Omega\,t)}{\Omega^2}\right)}_{>0}\,g\cos(\lambda)
\\y(t)=...\\
z(t)=...$$

and because $~x(t)> 0~$ the falling body  is deflected  towards east.

with

$$\Omega=7.2710^{-5}~[1/s]\quad,z_0=5000~[m]\quad,\lambda=\pi/3$$

the deflection when the  body reach the earth surface $(~z(t)=0~)$ is approximately $~3.5~[m]~$ to the east , $~y(t)=8~[mm]~$

notice

that the  $~\rm limit~x(t)_{\Omega\mapsto 0}=0~$ which is the case that you obtain "without Coriolis force "

---

for a rocket with initial velocity

$$\vec v_0=\begin{bmatrix}
  v_{x0} \\
  v_{y0} \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$x(t)=\left(\frac 12\frac t\Omega-\frac 14\frac{\sin(2\,\Omega\,t)}{\Omega^2}\right)\,g\cos(\lambda)+\frac 12 \frac{\sin(2\,\Omega\,t)}{\Omega}\,v_{x0}$$

hence $~v_{x0} > 0\quad\Rightarrow~x(t) >0~$
and  $~\rm limit~x(t)_{\Omega\mapsto 0}=v_{x0}\,t~$

Answer (score 0):

Coriolis force appears with any velocity (not in the direction of rotation axis) of body in Earth's system.
$$\vec{F}\sim \vec{v}\times\vec{\omega}$$
If any object is falling from anywhere through time it will obtain a velocity towards earth, so will experience coriolis force from the POV of people on the earth. Don't forget that for the Earth $\omega$ is orientated to the North pole. In rocket case $\vec{v}$ will still be pointed towards earth end the vector product $\vec{v}\times\vec{\omega}$ will still be pointed to the east.

But if rocket will have significant horizontal initial velocity (to the east or the west), there will be also a vertical component of coriolis force (in case of the east it will be pointed upwards, otherwise downwards)

Comment: Note also that if the force from the rocket's engine is directed "straight up", it will actually gain a westerly component to its motion due to the effects of the Coriolis force during its ascent.