# Quantifying the eastwards motion of an object in free-fall on the equator

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, angular-momentum, angular-velocity

I've been reviewing the correspondence between Hooke and Newton, trying to understand how an object falls eastwards, as predicted by Galileo as well. I've read two things:

1. As an object falls, it retains its original tangential velocity as radius decreases. Since there is a discrepancy between $v_{object} = (R + H) \omega$ and $v_{surface} = R \omega$, a falling object retaining its $v_{object}$ would move sideways faster than points below it, causing it to fall eastwards.
2. As an object falls, since angular momentum is conserved ($L = mr^2 \omega$), as $r$ decreases, $\omega$ increases. Since the object's angular velocity increases, it rotates faster than points below it, causing it to fall eastwards.

My question is: are these two the same thing? And how can we quantify the sideways displacement of an object that has fallen to Earth from a given height? I attempted to derive the below, for an object dropped from height $H$:

$$L = m(R+H)^2 \omega_{Earth}$$
$$L = m{R}^2 \omega_{objFinal}$$
Since angular momentum is conserved throughout the fall,
$$R^2 \omega_{objFinal} = (R+H)^2 \omega_{Earth}$$
$$\omega_{objFinal} = \frac{(R+H)^2}{R^2} \omega_{Earth}$$
$$v_{objFinal} = \frac{(R+H)^2}{R^2} v_{Earth}$$
$$v_{objFinal} = v_{Earth}(1 + \frac {2H}{R} + \frac {H^2}{R^2})$$
$$v_{objFinal} - v_{Earth}= \omega_{Earth}(2H + \frac {H^2}{R})$$

Because I don't have enough knowledge, I approximated the displacement assuming g is constant during the fall.
We assume the frame of reference of the Earth's surface:

Vertically,
$$t = \sqrt {\frac {2H}{g}}$$
Horizontally, I used equations of motion:
$$s = \omega_{Earth} \sqrt{\frac{H}{2g}} (2H + \frac{H^2}{R})$$

This returns an estimated sideways displacement of 2.94m for an object dropped from height 2km.

Comment: See also here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/729417/coriolis-force-effect-on-freely-falling-body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the two explanations of the phenomenon are both valid and I would say they are ultimately the same thing.

In your estimate, you first calculate the final eastward velocity (relative to the Earth), and assume that the object travels with that velocity throughout its entire motion. This is fine for an order-of-magnitude estimate, but will overestimate the actual distance a bit because the relative eastward velocity gradually works up to that value, so the average velocity is lower.

I think it's easiest to do the calculation in a reference frame rotating with the Earth. This is not an inertial frame, so we need to introduce [inertial forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force). The inertial force responsible for the eastward fall is the [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force).

Let the x-axis point to the east, and the y-axis downward. The Coriolis force is $\vec F_c = 2m\vec v\times\vec\Omega$, where the Earth's angular velocity $\vec \Omega$ points in the $+z$ (north) direction. To simplify the problem, let's consider only the vertical velocity component (which will be far greater than the eastward velocity) for purposes of calculating this force. Then, $F_c \approx 2m\Omega v_y$, eastward.

As you have calculated, the fall time (assuming constant $g$) is $T=\sqrt{2H/g}$. Now for the horizontal motion:
$$v_x(t) = \int\limits_0^ta_x(t')dt'=\int\limits_0^t2\Omega v_y(t')  dt'=\int\limits_0^t 2\Omega gt' dt'=\Omega gt^2$$
$$x(T)=\int\limits_0^Tv_x(t)dt=\int\limits_0^T\Omega gt^2dt=\frac{1}{3}\Omega gT^3=\sqrt{\frac{8\Omega^2H^3}{9g}}.$$
This gives $1.96\text{ m}$ for $H = 2\text{ km}$, so your estimate wasn't far off.

We don't have to work in the rotating frame and use the Coriolis force. Using your angular momentum conservation approach, the angular momentum of the object relative to the Earth's is
$$\Delta\omega = \left(\frac{R+H}{R+h(t)}\right)^2\Omega-\Omega$$
where $h(t)$ is the height from the Earth's surface at time $t$. Expanding the squared factor and keeping only terms linear in $H$ and $h$,
$$\Delta \omega \approx 2\frac{H-h(t)}{R}\Omega.$$
The velocity of the object's "shadow" (more precisely its projection) on the Earth's surface is
$$v_x(t)=R\Delta\omega\approx2[H-h(t)]\Omega=\Omega gt^2.$$
This is the same expression we got in the analysis in the rotating frame, the rest of the calculation is the same.